# How to checkif there are pending requests (Ajax and its variants) from browser

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, selenium, webdriver

Some of the sites I deal with have heavy ajax requests. I plan to wait for Ajax request completion before clicking for asserting for element. Currently I use

```
try {
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        for (int i = 0; i< timeoutInSeconds; i++) 
        {
            Object numberOfAjaxConnections = jsDriver.executeScript("return jQuery.active");
            // return should be a number
            if (numberOfAjaxConnections instanceof Long) {
                Long n = (Long)numberOfAjaxConnections;
                System.out.println("Number of active jquery ajax calls: " + n);
                if (n.longValue() == 0L)  break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("Web driver: " + driver + " cannot execute javascript");
    }
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

But it works well for Ajax requests but not for any similar requests with variants of jQuery libraries.

Note:

```
document.readyState == 'complete'
```

It doesn't work for Ajax requests or any other similar alternatives.

Neither tests are written by me or belong to single webapp. So I can't edit the webapp.

Comment: Do you mean you in other sites ajax calls are made without jquery? What's the purpose of injecting jquery?

Comment: Question is why you need that

Comment: If asynchronous requests are sent using other libraries like vanilla, does jquery.active still work? If not then I am asking wrong question.

Comment: If your application does not use jquery, you don't have any point of injecting it to the application.

Comment: https://github.com/sebuilder/se-builder/issues/188 gives little more context.

Comment: As I mentioned, unless the sites uses jquery, there is no point using jquery. Try to get something using plain javascript instead of jquery way

Comment: Can you check my answer posted below?

Comment: Good to know. Check and let me know.

Comment: Have you checked this SO question : [How to check if HTTP requests are open in browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267451/how-to-check-if-http-requests-are-open-in-browser)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer and it worked for few Ajax and non-ajax sites I checked. After this patch I no longer need to do implicit waits even for ajax heavy pages, LeGac pointed out the following code in one of his comments to the question.

```
public static void checkPendingRequests(FirefoxDriver driver) {
    int timeoutInSeconds = 5;
    try {
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

            for (int i = 0; i< timeoutInSeconds; i++) 
            {
                Object numberOfAjaxConnections = jsDriver.executeScript("return window.openHTTPs");
                // return should be a number
                if (numberOfAjaxConnections instanceof Long) {
                    Long n = (Long)numberOfAjaxConnections;
                    System.out.println("Number of active calls: " + n);
                    if (n.longValue() == 0L)  break;
                } else{
                    // If it's not a number, the page might have been freshly loaded indicating the monkey
                    // patch is replaced or we haven't yet done the patch.
                    monkeyPatchXMLHttpRequest(driver);
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        else {
           System.out.println("Web driver: " + driver + " cannot execute javascript");
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }    
}



public static void monkeyPatchXMLHttpRequest(FirefoxDriver driver) {
    try {
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            Object numberOfAjaxConnections = jsDriver.executeScript("return window.openHTTPs");
            if (numberOfAjaxConnections instanceof Long) {
                return;
            }
            String script = "  (function() {" +
                "var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;" +
                "window.openHTTPs = 0;" +
                "XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {" +
                "window.openHTTPs++;" +
                "this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {" +
                "if(this.readyState == 4) {" +
                "window.openHTTPs--;" +
                "}" +
                "}, false);" +
                "oldOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);" +
                "}" +
                "})();";
            jsDriver.executeScript(script);
        }
        else {
           System.out.println("Web driver: " + driver + " cannot execute javascript");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

After every step you would need to call

```
checkPendingRequests(driver);
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's javascript? It looks like java

Comment: in the angular app, this script is giving below warning in browser console and my service calls are failing too.
    [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is 
    deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's 
    experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: This is racy. You will get times when the page has already fired off ajax before your script runs. The best way to do this is with a browser extension. But that doesn't work for Chrome Headless mode.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work?
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    // Do stuff here...    
});
```

Comment: No it works only for ajax but the requests can be of any type.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSONP requests, you need to [enable the `active` handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446443/1064325):

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    options.global = true;
});
```

---

I think that the use of `active` is correct, but *possibly* the way you have used might return false in the `instanceof` conditions.

Optionally, [see another way to wait for jQuery ajax calls using `active` in `Selenium` tests](http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-jqueryactive-code-works.html):

```
browser.wait_for_condition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active === 0;", '30000')
```

Answer (score -3):

Based on our discussion over the comments, this might work for you.

**With prototype.js:**

```
var ACTIVE_REQUESTS = 0; // GLOBAL

ACTIVE_REQUESTS++
new Ajax.Request('/your/url', {
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    ACTIVE_REQUESTS--;
    // Handle the response content...
  }
}));

console.log("there are " + ACTIVE_REQUESTS + " open AJAX requests pending");
```

**With plain script:**

```
interValRef = 0;

interValRef = setInterval("checkState();",100)

function checkState(){
    if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
        clearInterval(interValRef);
        myFunc();
    }
}
```

Source: [Check Pending AJAX requests or HTTP GET/POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262473/check-pending-ajax-requests-or-http-get-post-request)

Comment: Doesnt work for me. I have checked with a pending ajax request. document.readyState is always 'complete'. checkout this http://tinypic.com/r/mr4qis/8. even with pending ajax requests, document.readyState is 'complete'