# How to select file in selenium webdriver from local machine from window popup without using sendkeys

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to select a file in selenium webdriver from local machine, but as selenium only supports web so I am not able to select file from local machine(Window poup) as it is not having any path in which I can fill the path of file through sendkeys. Is there any solution(using robotics class or autoIT tool or any other solution) from which I can able to select file from window. I have looked into autoIt tool but have not got enough details to implement, if anybody knows about it please reply on this. Please find attached screenshot for reference.

[Upload file from local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ioLF.png)
[window poup after clicking on choose file button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGuPJ.png)

Comment: Have a look at [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html - Autoit.
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-file-upload-using-robots - selenium Robot class. You can use anyone of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Robot class and this is much more easy than using AutoIT tool. Please find below code:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

    public void testUpload() throws InterruptedException
        {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("uploadfilebutton"));
//can use By cssSelector or name (path) as per convenience
            element.click();
            uploadFile("path to the file");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

        /**
         * This method will set any parameter string to the system's clipboard.
         */
        public static void setClipboardData(String string) {
            //StringSelection is a class that can be used for copy and paste operations.
               StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
               Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
            }

        public static void uploadFile(String fileLocation) {
            try {
                //Setting clipboard with file location
                setClipboardData(fileLocation);
                //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
                Robot robot = new Robot();

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have filename as "file" in File Upload

```
WebElement uploadfile = driver.findElement(By.name("file"));
uploadfile.sendKeys(filepath)

driver.findElement(By.id("file")).sendKeys("C:\\path\\to\\file.txt");
```

where C:\path\to\file.txt is the file location.

Comment: Don't use `new` as variable name.

Comment: new keyword is reserved by java so you can't create variable  name as new

Comment: i have changed it.. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sendKeys` with absolute path of image.

find a tag with `type=file` , it is not mandatory but selenium support this tag to uplaod file.

Also use waits to prevent from script getting fails

```
    WebElement button2 = mega.waitsss(driver, upload2);
    button2.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\logo\\Summit-Logo-900px.png");
    button2.click();        
}

WebElement waitsss(WebDriver driver, By elementIdentifier){
     Wait<WebDriver> wait =
                new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        return wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
                {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                           return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier);
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: I can't use sendkeys as it is not having field to give path. Directly clicking on choose file and select file

Comment: you can check after upload a file without click on upload if any element is changing or having value. there is a other option .. refer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021047/selenium-webdriver-upload-document-to-non-input-button

Comment: Else you can use AUTO IT but that make your script windows specific