# How to upload file using Selenium when there is no Input field on Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

This is the link: "https://uploadfiles.io/"
On this link I want to upload a file. Cannot use AutoIT and sikuli as I will be running Selenium. So will have to use setFileDetector method of selenium. But how can I even upload a file locally, as there is not Input Field if you check the HTML of the above link.

Comment: you can use Robot class. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711632/how-to-select-file-in-selenium-webdriver-from-local-machine-from-window-popup-wi and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java