# C# Selenium: How to click Accept button that is not in the DOM in a Sharepoint Folder Upload dialogue box

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, dialog, chrome-options

I have searched StackOverflow and could not find the correct solution for the following problem:

In an internal Sharepoint site, after clicking Upload, and then Folders, I use SendKeys.SendWait to input the directory location,. And then after sending "Enter" as Send.Keys.SendWait, a dialogue box appears, where I need to click the Upload button, but this element is not searchable, as it seems to be not part of the DOM. 
[image]

Here is the code snippet:

```
SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Automation\Testing\");

SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");

SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");

IAlert alert = Driver.driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

I have also tried to use JavaScript to handle this but it didn't help:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jsX = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

jsX.ExecuteScript("Object.defineProperty(BeforeUnloadEvent.prototype, 
'returnValue', { get:function(){}, set:function(){} });");
```

In another thread I noticed a suggestion to add "--disable-notifications" and "--disable-popup-blocking", but that didn't work either.

Here is the code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars", "start-maximized", "no-sandbox", "--disable-notifications", "--disable-popup-blocking");
 Driver.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

What is the best way to find and click the "Upload" in the dialogue box?

Comment: check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021047/selenium-webdriver-upload-document-to-non-input-button/40021733#40021733 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540188/upload-image-through-macos-window-with-selenium/49540578#49540578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use [InputSimulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator/) Nuget for simulating keyboard buttons events. On the screenshot `Cancel` button is selected, pressing `Tab` key might change the focus to `Upload` button, then `Enter` key may press `Upload` button:

```
var sim = new WindowsInput.InputSimulator();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
```

Comment: Hi Renat, Thank you for your feedback. I have just tried InputSimulator, it could not simulate the Upload click. It just simulated Enter key action that got the popup window disappeared without uploading any files.

Comment: @Sohel. Ok, I've update my answer. At first I got a wrong impression that  `Upload` was selected, but on the screenshot actually `Cancel` button is selected, so Tab -> Enter might still work.

Comment: Thank you Renat, your last modified code made it work. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it was helpful